# Spring Data Neo4j - (all) properties of RelationsshipEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

```
@NodeEntity
class A {
    @Relationship(type = "INCLUDES", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    List<B> bs;
}

@NodeEntity
class B {}

class C {
    int something;
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "INCLUDES")
class R {
    String property1;
    int property2;
    C c;

    @StartNode
    A a;

    @EndNode
    B b;
}
```

The goal to retrieve the relationship entity between two particular nodes (some instances of `A`and `B`) with **ALL** its properties.

I tried the following cypher query:

`MATCH (a:A)-[i:INCLUDES]-(b:B) RETURN i;`

However, this only gives me an empty result. If I retrieve all `INCLUDE`relationship entities with the default `Neo4jRepository.findAll()` implementation, I can see that all properties are set.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
MATCH (a:A)-[i:INCLUDES]-(b:B) RETURN i, a, b;
```

Comment: I solved in the meantime, the query as shown above is the one to use. Furthermore i created a query result class which has three fields: `A`, `INCLUDES`, and `B`.

Answer (score 1):

The custom query have to return also the `A`s and `B`s. Spring Data Neo4j needs them to distinguish if the relationship `INCLUDES` can be mapped. It may be that the returned `INCLUDE` does connect `C`s and `D`s in the database. This would lead to a wrong (and incomplete) mapped relationship.

Also keep in mind that the mapping in your `A` class should refer to `R` instead of `B` to get correct behaviour in all cases.